# How to make custom metric available for callbacks?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback

I defined a custom metric which I can use during `model.fit`:

```
N_CLASSES = 17
class SparseMeanIoU(ks.metrics.MeanIoU):
    def __init__(self,
                 y_true = None,
                 y_pred = None,
                 num_classes = None,
                 name = "Sparse_MeanIoU",
                 dtype = None):
        super(SparseMeanIoU, self).__init__(num_classes = num_classes,
                                             name = name, dtype = dtype)
        self.__name__ = "Sparse_MeanIoU"
    def get_config(self):
        return {"num_classes": self.num_classes, \
                "name": self.name, \
                    "dtype": self._dtype}
    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight = None):
        y_pred = tf.math.argmax(y_pred, axis = -1)
        return super().update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
    def __getstate__(self):
        variables = {v.name: v.numpy() for v in self.variables}
        state = { \
            name: variables[var.name] \
                for name, var in self._unconditional_dependency_names.items() \
                    if isinstance(var, tf.Variable)}
        state["name"] = self.name
        state["num_classes"] = self.num_classes
        return state
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__init__(name = state.pop("name"), \
            num_classes = state.pop("num_classes"))
        for name, value in state.items():
            self._unconditional_dependency_names[name].assign(value)

met = SparseMeanIoU(num_classes = N_CLASSES)
```

I get values during training and these values are recognized and displayed on TensorBoard.
However, I cannot use it in other callbacks, e.g. in `ModelCheckpoint` to save the model at checkpoints. Here, it fails with the message:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Can save best model only with Sparse_MeanIoU available, skipping.
```

I tried to pass the metric name without prefix, as well as `val_ + met.name`, which both did not work. I have seen examples where methods such as `on_epoch_end` were defined, however, I didn't really get what these are used for and whether it is required.

Callbacks:

```
monitor_metric = met.name #"val_" + met.name
cptdir = "/some/directory/"
logdir = "/some/other/directory/"
cllbs = [
    ks.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(cptdir, \
                                              "Epoch.{epoch:02d}.hdf5"), \
                                 monitor = monitor_metric, \
                                 mode = "max", \
                                 save_best_only = True, \
                                 save_freq = 5),
    ks.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir = logdir, histogram_freq = 5)
    ]
```

Model compile:

```
model.compile(optimizer = "Adam", loss = ks.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
                 metrics = [met, "sparse_categorical_accuracy"])
```

Model fit:

```
N_img = 100000 # number of images in training set
bs = 5 # batch size
args_fit = {"epochs" : 150,
            "steps_per_epoch" : np.ceil(N_img/bs),
            "validation_steps" : np.ceil(N_val/bs),
            "callbacks" : cllbs}
hist = model.fit(dataset["train"],
            validation_data = dataset["val"],
            **args_fit)
```

Comment: It could be helpful if you included your remaining code (ModelCheckpoint initalization, compile and fit calls) in your question.

Comment: @AlexK I added callbacks (checkpoint), compile and fit calls now.

Comment: Not noticing anything obvious right now, but the issue is probably with the `ks.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint()`. You could try checking the contents of your `hist.history` dictionary for the metric names, as prescribed in [docs](https://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint) (that page discusses this warning).

Comment: @AlexK Unfortunately, metric names don't seem to be the issue: The names in ```hist``` are loss
Sparse_MeanIoU 
sparse_categorical_accuracy 
val_loss 
val_Sparse_MeanIoU 
val_sparse_categorical_accuracy Which is what I expected and I already tried this by using ```"val_" + met.name``` (producing ```val_Sparse_MeanIoU ```) for the ```monitor``` argument...

Comment: Could it be that I would somehow pass the metric to the ```save``` function within the callback, similar to using ```model.save()``` outside the callback, where I would have to provide a ```dict``` with custom objects?

Comment: Try changing the `save_freq` parameter in `ModelCheckpoint()` to `save_freq = 'epoch'` (see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44107#issuecomment-747389632).

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't found this solution yet!